# can't find gem bundler Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Mac OS 13, rbenv.

> ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
>
> Rails 5.1.4
>
> Bundler version 1.16.1
>
> rbenv 1.1.1

I'm trying to start a new Rails application and then getting this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:382:in `bundle_command'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:416:in `run_bundle'
from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:24:in `perform'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

As I understand it has something to do with a version of Ruby but I have no idea how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Add the command that is raising the error to your **question**

Comment: Ruby 2.5 was going to include the bundler gem by default, but at the last minute they pulled it. So for now, we still need to do `gem install bundler` on a fresh Ruby 2.5 install before we can do `bundle install`. Incidentally, it looks like you are using your system Ruby. You should strongly consider using a Ruby environment manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: "Add the command that is raising the error to your question" I run `rails new app`

Comment: Yes, I did `gem install bundler` and I've installed Ruby 2.5.0 with rbenv.

Comment: Did you install ruby 2.3? I suspect that ruby 2.5 is not current default version. It seems like it still accesses to version 2.3 : from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/

Comment: I had Ruby 2.3 before 2.5. Maybe you are right. I just reinstall everything and it works now.

Comment: Sometimes, deleting the `$GEM_HOME` directory fixes this kind of issues.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may need to do a `gem install bundler` and get the bundler gem to get rails up and running.

Comment: Oh, I did it and it didn't help.

Comment: Good to know! It would be helpful if you included some solutions (and the outcomes) of things you've already tried. Also as @moveson has recommended a version control / env manager such as rbenv or rvm is extremely useful.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said it. My bad. So far I've tried `gem install bundler` and I use rbenv. That's all.

Comment: No worries. Did you have a previous install of ruby before using rbenv? What's the path if you run `which bundle`?

Comment: I just reinstall everything and it works now. Thanks for your help. Maybe the problem was that I installed Rails and after that  rbenv with new Ruby version.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score -1):

STEP (1): install the bundler gem:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Once completed, you should get a message similar to this:

```
Fetching: bundler-1.16.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 6 seconds
1 gem installed
```

STEP (2): try checking the bundler version:

```
bundle -v
```

You should get a version number like this:

```
Bundler version 1.16.1
```

STEP (3): now you can use bundle install:

```
bundle install
```

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Never install with sudo.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Your comment would be more useful if you've stated the reason rather than just giving a command. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Best-Practice%3A--Never-install-gems-with-sudo